# Is there a rule of thumb to set the space between columns?

Tags: spacing, typography, two-column

I've never heard about a convention to adjust the space between columns in a writing, it seems it depends on aesthetic sense--even in scientific literature---doesn't it?

Comment: The answer is OK for me (it already solved my doubt), I don't see why do you suggest the otherwise.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Quoting Felici, *The complete manual of typography*, p. 128:

> [T]he gutters between columns have to be in tune with both the texture
>   of the type---particularly the leading---and the widths of the margins
>   [...]. The page should appear as a harmonious whole, and the columns
>   should clearly relate to each other to create a sense of their being a
>   unified entity, albeit in several pieces. If the gutters are too wide,
>   the columns look like a series of unrelated text blocks. If the
>   gutters are too narrow, they begin to affect readability, as the eye
>   takes in part of the type from the next column every time it ranges
>   toward the end of the line.

On p. 129, Felici shows an example of justified text columns with too wide gutters and notes *"If the text were set ragged right, the effect would be even worse, as ragged margins make gutters seem wider."*

In my opinion, the "optimum" column width is about 1.5em to 2em, and the value of `\columnsep` in the standard classes (10pt) is so small as to affect readability.

Note: The following examples use the default font size of `10pt`. As the standard classes don't enlarge the value of `\columnsep` for the `11pt` and `12pt` sizes, their readability is affected even worse.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{microtype}

\textheight=180pt

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{microtype}

\textheight=180pt

\columnsep=1.6em

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I read somewhere that the "optimum" is around 0.8cm for font size 12, that is roughly 2em